# Why isn't this working in internet explorer 9?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

Hey, I'm having trouble with this side bar I'm trying to make. It wont look right when I look at it in interent explorer.

Heres a link, check it out in chrome of firefox then look at it in IE so you can see what I'm talking about. http://sickassvideos.com/player.php?id=1

Here is the code that creates those side bar boxes:

```
<div id="social">
                <h3>What we're about... </h3>
                <p>Our mission is to provide you with a continous and reliable stream of sick ass videos.</p>
            </div> <!-- socila -->
            <div id="social">
                <center>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td><script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script><fb:like-box href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/SickAssVideoscom/123296977742117" width="292" show_faces="false" stream="false" header="true"></fb:like-box></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                </center>
            </div> <!-- social -->

            <div id="social">
                <center>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td><img src="/images/logo.jpg" width="60px" height="60px"></td>
                        <td><h2>Coming soon!</h2><p>iPad and iPhone app</p></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                </center>
            </div> <!-- social -->
            <div id="social">
                <script type="text/javascript"><!--
                google_ad_client = "ca-pub-1520655484798685";
                /* Small ad */
                google_ad_slot = "2637780657";
                google_ad_width = 200;
                google_ad_height = 200;
                //-->
                </script>
                <script type="text/javascript"
                src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
                </script>
            </div>
```

Here is the style for id="social"

```
#content div#sidebar {
float: right;
}
#content div#social {
    float: right;
    width: 250px;
    height:;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    margin:0 0 15px 0;
    background: #FFF url() no-repeat;
    /* DROP Shadow 
    -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px #ccc;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px #ccc;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px #ccc;
    */
}
```

Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: I don't have IE9 but in IE6 it looks like a mess, DIVs are all around, entire content is not centered (aligned right by default), on Firefox and Safari, it looks nice but I can't tell you what's going on here...

Comment: RaphaelJS was able to crash IE 9 too... oh well, and IE 9's UI is quite ugly.  I think IE 9 is just for the team to earn top money, share in bonus from MS, and build rapport with the top management of MS, so that they "advance" in career

Comment: Right off the bat I noticed you shouldn't have multiple div's with the same id... Edit: A closer inspection reveals this seems to be the least of your problems. Consider putting your scripts inside the actual html tags... I believe IE9 can display properly if people follow some basic standards, just like the other browsers..

Comment: I stopped looking at your problem once the video started. That was damn funny.

Comment: Thanks everyone! I was affraid that might happen Brent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its badly coded css! but the issue for the boxes out of place is the facebook like button expanding too wide for the amount of margin your specifying.

also dont put analytics at top you put it at bottom, plus your missing a doctype

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    </head>

    <body>
<!--content ect-->

<!--analytics-->
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: there's no doc type because i have it saved as a *.php so it's included in a file with a doctype, but thank you for the relpy

Comment: @Mike it still needs tobe outputted to the browser